# React.js two-way binding on block elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to bind a value to a div with react so that I can maintain state for that element (eg. on-off)  It looks like I should be using LinkedStateMixin, but my experiment below proves that react doesn't support arbitrary attributes for block level elements.  Both elements have default values but the div e.target.value returns undefined from its onclick handler whereas the input element value has been properly set.  Any idea how to bind data to the div? Thanks!

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {message: 'Hello!'};
    },
    render: function () {
        var valueLink = this.linkState('message');
        var handleClick = function(e) {
            console.log(e.target.value);
            valueLink.requestChange(e.target.value);
        };
        return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onClick={handleClick} defaultValue={valueLink.value} />
            <div onClick={handleClick} defaultValue={valueLink.value}>
                {this.state.message}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    }
});

React.render(<Component />, document.body);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/su8r5Lob/

Comment: What are you trying to do?  I'm not seeing why you're trying to provide a value/defaultValue for a div... divs don't support the value property.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand I'm trying to create a toggle switch without input elements. I know that div's dont support the value property, but I thought that valueLink might create its own value reference regardless of the element type.  I just wanted to maintain a class value in the element.  But, after talking to my buddy, I realize that I need to change the paradigm as per interactions described here: http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code does not work is because `<div>` elements do not have a `value` property. Only elements that receive user input have it. So when `handleClick` is called, `valueLink.requestChange` receives `undefined` as a parameter.

I've updated your Fiddle a little bit, and now it does support two-way binding for the `onChange` event.

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {message: 'Hello!'};
    },
    render: function () {
        var valueLink = this.linkState('message');
        var handleClick = function(e) {
            console.log(e.target.value);
            valueLink.requestChange(e.target.value);
        };
        return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={handleClick} value={valueLink.value} />
            <input type="text" onChange={handleClick} value={valueLink.value} />
        </div>
    );
    }
});

React.render(<Component />, document.body);
```

But, if you want to bind it to a `div` element, I give you this suggestion. I'm not sure if it is exactly what you expect, but here it is:

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {message: 'Hello!'};
    },
    render: function () {
        var valueLink = this.linkState('message');
        var handleClick = function(e) {
            console.log(e.target.value);
            valueLink.requestChange(e.target.value);
        };
        return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onChange={handleClick} value={valueLink.value} />
            <div onClick={handleClick.bind(this, {target: {value: 'someDivValue'}})} defaultValue={valueLink.value}>
                {this.state.message}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    }
});

React.render(<Component />, document.body);
```

Note that I gave the `div` a default value that is going to be set to the valueLink everytime the user clicks it. And I had to change the event on the input to `onchange` so it can update its value when the user types something.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  This is one way to do it (and pretty much what I asked for), but after discussing with my buddy, I realize that my approach to the problem was all wrong.  Consider the answer below which hopefully illustrates the 'Thinking in React' way to do it.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the answer below is more "Reacty"

Answer (score 2):

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    mixins: [React.addons.LinkedStateMixin],
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            message: 'Hello!',
            active: false
        };
    },
    inputClick : function(e) {
        console.log(e.target.value);
    },
    toggleActive : function(e){
        console.log('div state', this.state.active);
        var newState = !this.state.active;
        this.setState({active: newState});
    },
    render: function () {
        var cx = React.addons.classSet;
        var valueLink = this.linkState('message');
        var classes = cx({
            'base-class': true,
            'element-active': this.state.active
        });

        return (
        <div>
            <input type="text" onClick={this.inputClick} defaultValue={valueLink.value} />
            <div onClick={this.toggleActive} className={classes}>
                {this.state.message}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
   }
});

React.render(<Component />, document.body);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/su8r5Lob/1/

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand does this answer better explain what I was trying to do?  Hopefully this will help someone.